# Variable inaccessible inside callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, child-process

I have a variable `deleteFlag` which is inaccessible inside a function even though the variable's scope is global.

***Explanation (Pls refer my code simultaneously):***

Here, I am trying to get a MongoDB collection details, the collection store a *date* document `(result[i].date)`. The variable `difResult` stores the difference between the current date and the date fetched from MongoDB. And let's say if the value of `difResult` is more than a specific threshold then handle respective if-else conditions.

My if block i.e. `if(difResult>20000)` has a `child-process, exec` function and a callback function to delete MongoDB collection, now in this function I am trying to access var `deleteFlag` which is sort inaccessible.
*Why? And how can I make is accessible inside my function?*

**app.js**

```js
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("dbName");
  dbo.collection("colName").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var difResult = Math.round((today - result[i].date));
      var deleteFlag = result[i].date; // Declared here and should be accessbile within the function
      console.log("Delete Flag " + deleteFlag.toISOString()); //Show correct value here
      console.log("Result Date " + result[i].date);
      if (difResult > 20000) {
        var result2 = cp.exec("rm -rf /path/" + deleteFlag.toISOString(), function(error, stdout, stderr) {
          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            return res1.status(500).json({
              error: "Failed!"
            });
          } else {
            MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", {
              useUnifiedTopology: true
            }, function(err, db) {
              console.log("Delete Flag From Collection ", +deleteFlag.toISOString());
              //The above console log gives NaN or null value
              //Suggest that var deleteFlag is not accessible inside this callback function
              if (err) throw err;
              var dbo = db.db("dbName");
              var myquery = {
                date: deleteFlag
              };
              dbo.collection("colName").deleteOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document deleted");
                db.close();
              });
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Else msg");
      }
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call the database twice you can optimize your code and use it like this

```
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("dbName");
  dbo.collection("colName").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var difResult = Math.round((today - result[i].date));
      var deleteFlag = result[i].date; // Declared here and should be accessbile within the function
      console.log("Delete Flag " + deleteFlag.toISOString()); //Show correct value here
      console.log("Result Date " + result[i].date);
      if (difResult > 20000) {
        var result2 = cp.exec("rm -rf /path/" + deleteFlag.toISOString(), function(error, stdout, stderr) {
          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            return res1.status(500).json({
              error: "Failed!"
            });
          } else {
          var myquery = {
                date: deleteFlag
              };
              dbo.collection("colName").deleteOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document deleted");
              });
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Else msg");
      }
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

However if for whatever reason you need to call the database twice then store `deleteFlag` values in an array and then access the array wherever you like